# ASPNET modifies the html

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have made a group of webpages they look the same in IE, Mozilla, Opera and Chrome and they are approved on the W3C online validators. My problem comes when I put the html code in ASP.NET. It spoils the design, specially when I am using divs with position absolute. I am using Visual Studio.NET 2008 SP1 and I still have not put any control on my webpages, the html code is still clean.

Something interesting is the fact that I have used before ASPNET MVC and it never gave me this kind of problems.

Thanks

Comment: ASP.NET can do this in so many ways... you're really going to have to be more specific.

Answer (score -1):

Better you can go with the positioning of the div's relatively. As when we use the absolute positioned div's and resize the browser, the content display will be not inline with the flow of the document.

However, if you can give more details of how the design was affected, we can discuss on ways of overcoming the same. [VS IDE is specific to IE].